# Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please help me in understanding what am i doing wrong here. I am new to JavaScript programming.I am getting this error:

> Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined.

```
//Return the first letter of given string. 
function titleCase(str) {
  var newStr = str.split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i <= newStr.length; i++) {
    console.log(newStr[i].charAt(0));
  }
}
titleCase("Hi there.");

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: `<=` should be `<`.

Comment: See [*For each over array in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) for the correct ways to loop through an array's contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you looping condition needs to get updated. See you string include 4 words but iterating loop till i become 4 and starting from 0 i.e iteration will be done 5 times

```js
function titleCase(str){
    var newStr = str.split(' ');
    for(var i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++){
        console.log(newStr[i].charAt(0));
    }
}
titleCase("Coding is not easy");
```

Comment: "...until `i` becomes **`4`**", not 5.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `=` sign from this line

`for(var i = 0; i <= newStr.length; i++){`

```js
function titleCase(str){
    var newStr = str.split(' ');
    for(var i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++){
        console.log(newStr[i].charAt(0));
    }
}
titleCase("Coding is not easy");
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function titleCase(str){
    var newStr = str.split(' ');
    for(var i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++){
        console.log(newStr[i].charAt(0));
    }
}
titleCase("Coding is not easy");
```

`i <= newStr.length` you were iterating till equal length, and starting from zero. There the problem is at end you are getting an undefined value.
In your case the newStr array length is 5, and you are trying to get 5th element as well, while there is only 4 values present.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

For developers coming with `Angular Universal`, `domino`, `Server-Side Rendering (SSR)` topics; it might be due to the reason you're using `xhr2` package.

Therefore, removing it fixes the problem. Most probably you're using somehow like `(global as any).XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');`, then simply drop the line. More about this in [#830 (comment)](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/830#ref-issue-734772549)